# ASP.NET WebForms: Is it possible to store/update session data within a thread in a load balanced environment using SQL server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, multithreading, session, webforms

We are using a ASP.NET WebForms website with a load balancer storing the session variables using SQL server (for now I cannot change this configuration).

I need to upload a file and process it which can take some time. I would like to give the user feedback of the current process.

I found a solution where I start a thread processing the file. This web method call returns directly with an unique guid identifying the process. At the client I call a web method to get the current status of the process. The thread updates the process status which is stored in de session.

The problem is that this doesn't works in a load balanced environment as the session is serialized to the SQL server when the initial process request is called.

My question is (I searched a lot and could not find an exact answer):

**Is there a way to update the session variable inside a thread so that it is re-serialized to the SQL server?**

Comment: No it is not possible to access a session within a thread - with out the real page. The only way is to make your personal session class and manager

Comment: Did you think using an async Task in webform (ex : Page.RegisterAsyncTask ) and then updating the session from the callback ?

Comment: Is the processing of the file separate from the upload? Could you build a custom HTTP Handler and create a class that implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState to output process to session?